# Google App Engine The SSL certificate provided could not be inserted. xn- domain

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, google-app-engine, x509

I try installing Comodo Certificate that I ordered in SSLs.com on Google App Engine Custom Domain. But I have error:

> The SSL certificate provided could not be inserted.

I checked that my key is 2048-bit length:

```
# openssl rsa -in myserver2.key.pem -text -noout
Private-Key: (2048 bit)
```

And made sure that my certificate appended to ca-bundle:

```
cat xn--80aaxfchnde0hb.com.crt xn--80aaxfchnde0hb.com.ca-bundle > concat.crt
```

Besides that I verified md5 and CAfile:

```
# openssl verify -verbose -CAfile concat.crt concat.crt 
concat.crt: OK

# openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in concat.crt |openssl md5
(stdin)= f83d...c3d

# openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in myserver2.key.pem | openssl md5
(stdin)= f83d...c3d
```

Also I tried to convert the certificate in PEM

```
openssl x509 -inform PEM -in concat.crt > concat.pem
```

I want to get a certificate for xn- domain.

Answer (score 2):

Google App Engine support for SSL certificates, quote from [article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#app_engine_support_for_ssl_certificates)

> App Engine supports the following certificate types:
>
> - Single Domain/Hostname
> - Self-signed
> - Wildcard
> - Subject Alternative Name (SAN) / Multi Domain
>
> It requires some things of your certificates and keys:
>
> - Private Key and Certificate should be uploaded in PEM format.
> - Private Keys must not be encrypted.
> - A certificate file can contain at most five certificates; this number 
>     includes chained and intermediate certificates.
> - All subject names on the host certificate should match
>     or be subdomains of the user's verified domains.
> - Private keys must use RSA encryption.
> - Maximum allowed key modulus: 2048 bits
>
> If the host certificate requires an intermediate or chained certificate (as many
>   Certificate Authorities (CAs) issue), you will need to append the
>   intermediate or chained certificates to the end of the public
>   certificate file.
>
> Some App Engine features use special subdomains. For example, an
>   application can use subdomains to address application services, or to
>   address different versions of your application. To use these with SSL,
>   it makes sense to set up a SAN or wildcard certificate. Wildcard
>   certificates only support one level of subdomain.

For steps to how obtain a certificate visit [this article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#obtaining_a_certificate).